# What does this indexing mean in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, matrix

I saw this code by someone and I just can't understand what it means.

I have a matrix shaped (4000x32), this matrix gets indexed by a tuple with 2 values, first value is an array (4000,), the second is a matrix shaped (7x4000), the final results is a matrix shaped (7,4000). This looks like this

```
data_padded #4000x32 matrix
>>> array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])


data.shape[0]
>>> 4000

pm_intervals_padded # 7x4000 matrix
>>> array([[ 1,  1,  4, ...,  1,  2,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  5, ...,  2,  3,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  6, ...,  3,  4,  3],
       ...,
       [ 5,  5,  8, ...,  5,  6,  5],
       [ 6,  6,  9, ...,  6,  7,  6],
       [ 7,  7, 10, ...,  7,  8,  7]], dtype=int64)



index_arrays = np.arange(data.shape[0]), pm_intervals_padded

index_arrays # it is now a tuple with a 4000x1 vector and a 7x4000 matrix
>>> (array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 4000, 4001, 4002]),
     array([[ 1,  1,  4, ...,  1,  2,  1],
        [ 2,  2,  5, ...,  2,  3,  2],
        [ 3,  3,  6, ...,  3,  4,  3],
        ...,
        [ 5,  5,  8, ...,  5,  6,  5],
        [ 6,  6,  9, ...,  6,  7,  6],
        [ 7,  7, 10, ...,  7,  8,  7]], dtype=int64))
```

Now the actual indexing performed

```
max_pm = data_padded[index_arrays]

max_pm # 7x4000 matrix
>>> array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.12076883, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.11525869, ..., 0.        , 0.13826102,
        0.        ],
       [0.1493025 , 0.03919184, 0.07849565, ..., 0.08812743, 0.13011599,
        0.12065721],
       ...,
       [0.1001403 , 0.14246948, 0.06306174, ..., 0.12461658, 0.10053093,
        0.22260186],
       [0.12709181, 0.11613311, 0.08537152, ..., 0.08284497, 0.05215555,
        0.09772167],
       [0.10410622, 0.08596166, 0.02676092, ..., 0.09114279, 0.07044313,
        0.05734969]])
```

I really don't understand how "data_padded" changed from a 4000x32 matrix to a 7x4000 matrix.

Comment: You can index an array with another array that has a higher dimension. Note that for an array `a` of any dimension and a positive integer `k`, `a[k]` is equivalent to `a[k,...]`. When you compute `a[b]` where `a` and `b` are arrays such that elements of `b` are suitable indices for `a` (i.e. integers between `0` and `a.shape[0]-1`), the result will be a b-shape array whose values are the `a[k]` for k in b. When `a` is of dimension>1, `a[b]` will end up being bigger than `b`, having a shape of `(*b.shape, *a.shape[1:])` if i'm not mistaking anything

Answer (score 0):

It is numpy doing broadcasting and indexing. Take this simple example:

```
# 2x2
data = np.array([[1,2],
                 [3,4]])

index_arrays = (np.array([0,1]), np.array([[0,1],
                                           [0,0],
                                           [0,1]]))

data[index_arrays]
```

Numpy will first broadcast `np.array([0,1])` to match the latter, so `index_arrays` becomes:

```
index_arrays = (np.array([[0,1],
                          [0,1],
                          [0,1]]), 
                np.array([[0,1],
                          [0,0],
                          [0,1]]))
```

then numpy simply retrieves elements from `data` for each index pair (i, j), with i from the first array in `index_arrays` and j from the second, first retrieve
element at coordinate `(0,0)`, then `(1,1)`, `(0,0)`, `(1,0)`, etc.
So the return would be of the same size as your index array:

```
array([[1, 4],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.arange(data.shape[0])
```

is (4000,) shape (not 1x4000).

```
pm_intervals_padded   # (7,4000)
```

These `broadcast` together to select (7,4000) points.  For the purpose of `broadcasting` (4000,) and (1,4000) behave the same.  `broadcasting` is a fundamental `numpy` behavior, applicable to operations like addition as well as this indexing.

Indexing with the tuple `(x,y)` is equivalent to:

```
data_padded[(x, y)]
data_padded[x, y]
```

alternatively you could use

```
data_padded(np.arange(4000)[:,None], pm_intervals_padded.T]
```

This indexes with a (4000,1) and (4000,7), resulting in a (4000,7) selection.